# Able to build nexus image e on ppc64le, facing issues while spinning up container using locally built image

Tags: nexus3

We are trying to build [nexus](https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3/blob/main/Dockerfile) image on ppc64le, able to build the image on ppc64le architecture. However while spinning up container facing below issue:

```
ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM Felix - Bundle com.github.luben.zstd-jni [250] Error starting reference:file:system/com/github/luben/zstd-jni/1.4.8-7/zstd-jni-1.4.8-7.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.github.luben.zstd-jni [250](R 250.0):
missing requirement [com.github.luben.zstd-jni [250](R 250.0)] osgi.native;
```

As per investigation it was observed that the OSGI support is already available for ppc64le, as per the official site: https://docs.osgi.org/reference/osnames.html.
zstd-jni artifacts can be found here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/luben/zstd-jni/1.4.8-7/

Any suggestions/comments are welcomed.
Thanks in-advance.